# Proper way to bind in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am implementing a program that would have multiple DataGrids in the UI. 2 grids would be exactly similar except they're for different collections. 1 grid will be different from the 2. I was wondering what would be the best approach of implementing this.

While experimenting with it, I ended up just having 3 regular DataGrids each one bound to an ObservableCollection. I ended up implementing 3 different event handlers for each grid for any event that I need (ie. PreviewDragEnter). Obviously, this implementation is very messy as I have all the code in 1 .cs file.

Now I'm thinking if this would be possible. Create a class MyClass that has a property for the observable collection and implement the event handlers that I need and use this to create an object to be used by datagrid 1 and 2.

From my MainWindow.xaml, will I be able to add 2 datagrids. Have 1 datagrid bind to MyClassInstance1 and the other to MyClassInstance2? And then, for the events in the datagrid, will I be able to say MyClassInstance2.EventHandler? Am I in the right track here?

Other suggestions are welcome too.

Answer (score 1):

WPF applications are generally implemented using the MVVM pattern.  That's Model-View-View Model, where the Model is composed of the data (usually in a database or XML, but it's up to you what the Model is), the View is the XAML describing your windows, and the View Model is a collection of objects that contain the business logic.

There are documents & tutorials on the web describing how to implement an application in MVVM.  Do a search for "MVVM pattern" to find some.

Comment: I've read up on MVVM and I would see simple examples on creating  viewmodel classes and binding. I guess my question is specific to being able to create a class that would have properties and commands/events and have the 2 datagrids bind to 2 instances of that class?